# [SOLVED] rosrun - Couldn't find executable

Tags: ros-melodic, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Melodic on Fedora 33 and all seems to work properly, for example, I've tried to run the turtlesim node with turtle_teleop_key and turtlesim_node and they work as expected.

So, I created my node and put it under ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/ode_simulator, compiled with `catkin build ode_simulator`, all went smooth.

Then I tried to run it, with `rosrun ode_simulator ode_simulator` but it gives the following error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named ode_simulator below /home/MY_NAME/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ode_simulator
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/MY_NAME/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ode_simulator
```

However the package exists and is found by ROS, since running `rospack find ode_simulator` gives:

```
/home/MY_NAME/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/share/ode_simulator
```

My **CMakeLists.txt** is quite long and mostly commented out, but the following lines are present and not commented:

```
include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(ode_simulator src/ode_simulator.cpp src/ode_simulator_node.cpp src/simulator_odefun.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ode_simulator ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

From these lines I understand that there should be an executable called ode_simulator, but it seems that there isn't one.

This is what is present in the ode_simulator folder in ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/ode_simulator, command `ls *`:

```
CMakeLists.txt  package.xml

config:
ode_simulator_params.yaml

include:
ode_simulator  simulator_odefun.h

launch:
ode_simulator.launch

src:
ode_simulator.cpp  ode_simulator_node.cpp  simulator_odefun.cpp
```

Of course there is `source ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/setup.zsh` in my **.zshrc**.

Any help is appreciated, if more info is needed please tell me and I'll provide it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390554/%5Bsolved%5D-rosrun---couldn%27t-find-executable/) by [0novanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/40578/0novanta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-11**:
There isn't really a need to edit the titles of questions that have an answer. The green checkmark they show on the index page already clearly communicates there is an accepted answer.

**Comment by [0novanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/40578/0novanta/) on 2021-11-11**:
I know that there is the green checkmark, but when looking for posts on, e.g., Google I find it helpful to know if a question has been solved or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be using an `install` space, but don't have an `install(..)` command in your `CMakeLists.txt` which actually installs your `ode_simulator` node (or at least: your `CMakeLists.txt` quotes don't show any).

It's likely that's the problem: `roslaunch` uses your `install` space (ie: `install_isolated`) as you `source` it, but the binary will only be present in the `devel_isolated` space.

To fix this, you'd have to make sure to `install(..)` the `ode_simulator` executable.

---

Having written that: I would actually advise you, unless you have a good reason, to *not* use your bootstrap Catkin workspace as a regular "development" workspace.

Instead, create a new workspace which extends/overlays the `install_isolated` space of your bootstrap workspace, and then do all of your own development in that second workspace.

Benefits: faster compile times (as only your second workspace will need to be crawled and built), you can use the `devel` space of your second workspace (`install(..)` is not absolutely necessary any more) and you don't risk running into problems mucking up your bootstrap workspace.

If you want to make things "more like on Ubuntu" (or: systems for which binaries are distributed) and you have the permissions, you could consider running `catkin_make_isolated --install-space=/opt/ros/melodic`. That would copy the `install` space of your bootstrap repository to `/opt/ros/melodic`, exactly like on other systems. You would then still use a second workspace to work on your own packages, but it would extend `/opt/ros/melodic` instead of a directory in your `$HOME` directory.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [0novanta](https://answers.ros.org/users/40578/0novanta/) on 2021-11-10**:
I'm sorry I did not update the question, I did exactly as you said: new workspace that overlays `install_isolated` and it works like a charm!